# Unable to find PdfToImageConverter in EvoPdf 6.15 library

Tags: c#, .net, evopdf

I am using the `EvoPdf` nuget package version 6.15 and I'm unable to work with the `PdfToImageConverter` utility as mentioned in the sample code.

http://www.evopdf.com/pdf-to-image-converter.aspx

Is this code referenced in a separate package to the core HTML to PDF code?

Many thanks

Comment: I am using itextsharp library for the same purpose https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/itextsharp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the code is in the `EvoPdfToImage` assembly which can only be downloaded as a binary and referenced.

http://www.evopdf.com/download.aspx